# Error when publish Google Play Books

Tags: epub, calibre, google-play-books

This is my first time to publish my book on Google Play Books. I already publish on Amazon without any problem. Then, I use Calibre to convert my ebook to ePub format, and upload to Google Play Books. There is an error:

```
Unable to sanitize epub
```

I did look in Google forum, but it didn't help.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. How to publish a book is off-topic.

Comment: where I can post this on StackExchange network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to fix that issue:

First, validate ePub file in: http://validator.idpf.org/

We can see some problems in there. And we need to fix it.

Second, use Calibre to edit ePub file (Right click to the book -> Edit book)

We can see a lot of HTML files, CSS files,... Please follow the errors that validator warn, and fix it.

Save it, and upload to Google Play Books again.

That's solved!